# How to print to a home network printer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, network-printer

I have a Windows 7 computer with a USB direct to a printer. I want my `Surface Pro 3` (SP3) to be able to print to this printer over the network. The printer works from the computer that is directly connected. The `HomeGroup` shows as `Joined`. The printer is set as shared. From the `SP3` I do not see the printer even when I use `Find Printer` from the `Print` dialog. I have been searching I just don't understand any of the results' directions. How can I finish setting this up. Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with that method. How to get the IP and add it that way?

Comment: I tried a search for that route and I don't have an IP address in the general tab for the printer properties. This is why I came here - all the searches bring to things that don't exist or just do not work.

Comment: HP Deskjet F4500

Comment: It seems like this printer supports connecting to wireless networks, on page 5 of the document below. That would be the easiest way to make the printer accessible by all devices; they would just communicate with it over the network using the printer's IP address: http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01859574.pdf . I can't vouch if this works for routers that don't use WPS (the little button on the router that lets people automatically connect)

Comment: I knew you were going to go there. That does not seem to be a viable option. This printer seems to be the bane of my existence. I have set that up in the past and every time a computer is turned off or the wifi goes out I would have to go thru the same 15 minute process of resetting it up again and tech support could not even help with this. I guess I will just go get a new one since nothing will work.

Comment: There's a way to get it to work, but what you just said makes it sound like there's a network issue. Printers are a pain in themselves, but good luck with it

Comment: Sure, but what?

Comment: Can't tell without seeing it that'd be a completely different question

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, verify that Homegroup printing is actually setup and working.

[image]

If it is, then I have to admit that I haven't actually touched Homegroup since the beta years ago and the first part of this answer is guessing... Looking at the homegroup screens, I can see it links to the traditional advanced sharing settings, so, I will help with my knowledge there.

Based on this, I am guessing that Homegroup utilise the standard print sharing features... So, I would first make sure that your network is set to the private profile :

[image]

Then click on `Advanced Sharing Settings` from the link on the left. From here, make sure for the Private profile that `File and printer sharing` is set to `Turn on file and printer sharing`.

If it is and you are still having issues, I am not actually sure what homegroup does to enable/help the printer sharing, but, we can do this the traditional way:

Go to `Devices and Printers`, Right click on the printer and choose `Printer Properties`.

[image]

From here, click the `Sharing` tab and make sure that the printer is actually shared.

Next, go back to the Surface and try to add again.

If you are still having issues, verify that the workgroup is set to the same on both machines. and finally, I would try to add it via the ip rather than the search - but hopefully this has helped.

Comment: Network is set to Home since private is not a choice. I did right click the printer and chose `Share this Printer`. When trying to add it back and not finding in the window - I selected the `I did not find the printer I want` link and tried to add the printer by `\\computer name\printer name` as found in the Printer Properties window and it will not connect. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DonA - I am always happy to help... If you want to load teamviewer on both machines (or another method) I'm happy to quickly try to take a look and help you further - I can then write up the solution after.... If you do want to do this, let me know.

Comment: I am back from work and was able to the computer to be seen on the network, but when I try to click on it there is an error "Windows is unable to connect to `//comp name`" why is it missing the computer/domain? How can I change that? Windows diagnostics does not help. Thanks

Comment: This is a tough one without being there in person. If you have a few minutes, I can help via teamviewer or some other remote method... If you are interested in this, please come in to chat or contact me (details in profile).

Comment: More tinkering and I can now access the network printer. On to the folders/files. Thanks for the offer to help.